# Difference of difficulties between fields of research

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, working-time

Is it true that research (Ph.D...) in some fields requires more work and are harder than others ?
For example to publish an article in computer science is it more difficult than to do in telecommunications ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a very subjective topic. What someone might consider hard, others might find easy. It all depends on your skills and education.

Comment: something is hard if the work requires much effort and precision, and this agreed on by a community, it is not related to a person's education

Comment: The differences are huge, not only within CS, but even within the same field of CS depending on the type of venue you address (top conference vs. good conference).

Comment: @lighthousekeeper That should be the right answer (if you make it an answer)

Comment: Deleting questions with thoughtful answers iby defacing them s not good practice. I  have rolled back the  edit. You can choose to close your own question if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that everybody is very well aware of the challenges and difficulties in their own discipline, but only have an outsiders view on the others. There are those who switched disciplines, who have a somewhat better view on both. However, remember that there was reason why they switched. So they are unlikely to be representative for their old discipline. Moreover, people differ; tasks that are difficult for some are easy for others and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

It is undoubtedly subjective.

But take the same researcher or PhD student. Being in an interdisciplinary field and having a rather interdisciplinary formation I am hundred percent sure some research lines potentially lead to more papers than others. No doubt about it.

However your question asks two different things, or better seems to assume the number of publications as an indicator for the easiness/hardness of a field...
This is an unfair take, perhaps. I am not sure that publications number is, alone, a good indicator of the amount of dedicated work required. In simple terms, spending week ends in the lab working in topic A is more likely to lead to a paper then doing the same on topic B. Yet, weekends were spent in lab, both ways.

Comment: Downvote could have add a comment. It is simple as this : I worked really hard and publish really a lot. Another topic / technique and the same me would have publish much less.